# Add additional user column to week view calendar

Tags: angular, typescript, calendar, schedule

I'm trying to make a calendar with the user's name as a column in the week view, I'm using angular-calendar 0.28.22. [I found this example online, but I didn't understand the solution. https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar/issues/699 ] [1] so if anyone has any other solution of how to make roughly the same schedule (with open source code) please let me know.
Thank you.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiv8J.png

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: @Faisal no unfortunately, still looking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

There's an official example with the user's names as columns in day view.
I realize your asking for week view, but I hope it still helps and you can go from there: https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/day-view-scheduler